# Help request to identify soldering station

Tags: soldering

I acquired this soldering station which does not have the manufacturer or model number on it. If someone could help to identify it, I would be very grateful.

Thank you,

Tom[image]

Comment: Does the person whom you have acquired it from know the make and model?

Answer (score 1):

The design is very similar to [Mercury Ceramic Soldering Station](https://www.commsandsound.com/mercury-ceramic-soldering-station-48w.html). Perhaps it is one of the older models with some parts removed.

Update: Or [this one](http://www.tedweber.com/ss-1), which looks rebranded same one.